# GDB gives Segmentation Fault (gdb... not my program)

Tags: gdb, segmentation-fault, cluster-computing, icc

By the title, I mean it's not the program being debugged that segfaults, it's gdb itself.

So I'm just trying to create a breakpoint; when I press  gdb dies.

[image]

I like to believe that this is not a bug, but some confusion in background. Because the intel compiler (icc) has been updated on this computer.

This machine is running over two ssh sessions in a dual socket computer with 2 x Intel Xeon X5650 @ 2.67GHz (6 cores each, 12 total, 24 with multi-threading), with 48 Gb of DRAM (NUMA), and 2 GPU (Tesla C2070 and Tesla C2090 [this one is not properly installed]). This is running Cent OS:

```
~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b5.bsys.dev.centos.org)
  (gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed May 16
  00:01:37 BST 2012
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not my subject area, but: did you recompile `gdb` on this machine? Or is this retrieved from the Centos repo?

Comment: I'm not sure, who install this stuff was the cluster admin... but it was working nice before the icc updated.

Comment: Ah, ok. Are you in a position to get the source tarball and recompile in a non-path location, so you can see if that works?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not sure if will have the time for that...
Last week I build gcc and took the all day... end of semester it's very complicated.